# Not able to boot into arch linux after installing arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, windows, grub

Hello i'm in a pretty dangerous situation right now,i was installing Arch-Linux into my computer and my grub didn't install correctly as it was showing sector 32 was in use by flexnet and it didn't report any error, on ignoring the warning i followed rest of the instructions from www.fosslinux.com/7117/how-to-install-arch-linux-complete-guide.htm 
On exiting from arch-chroot i rebooted my system only to see a grub prompt not showing options to boot into arch linux or windows.
Here are some things that i had done previously before installing:
I had created two partitions on my hard disk both ext2 to differentiate from other ntfs partitions.
I installed the base system in /dev/sda5 and created the swap system in /dev/sda6 within the same hard disk.
How do i boot into arch linux or if not possible then how do i restore to boot my system to windows back?.

Answer (score 0):

You should always only follow the [official guide to install Arch Linux](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installation_guide).

The guide you linked misses a crucial step and is therefore outdated (unlike the wiki article above).

[Three months ago](https://www.archlinux.org/news/base-group-replaced-by-mandatory-base-package-manual-intervention-required/) the Arch Linux team changed how the `base` package is defined and you will now miss a linux kernel if you only install `base` (alongside some other useful software)

Things to do:

- **Read** the ArchWiki guide as linked above
- boot into your arch ISO
- mount your partitions you already created
- run `pacstrap` with your desired kernel and other software you may want
- I don't use GRUB but you probably will need to re-run `grub-mkconfig`